# The method add(String) in the type LinkedList<String> is not applicable for the arguments (LinkedListDemo.Node)

Tags: java, methods, addition

I am trying to create an a linked list where i can store the group and i have did it somehow but i am facing problem in adding the node which is having grp as data in it so please look in to this and please help me to solve this

trying to create and the group of the members and adding them into one node and forming a linkedlist of it

but getting this error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
The method add(String) in the type LinkedList is not applicable for the arguments (LinkedListDemo.Node)

```
at LinkedListDemo.addGrp(LinkedListDemo.java:67)
at LinkedListDemo.main(LinkedListDemo.java:124)
```

```
import java.util.*;

public class LinkedListDemo {
    class group
    {
        String leadname;
        String members[]=new String[8];
        String grpname;
        public group(String l, String gnm)
        {
        this.leadname=l;
        this.grpname=gnm;
        }
    }

LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
Node head=null;




static class Node {
    group data ;
    Node next = null;

    Node(group g) {
        this.data = g;
    }

    Node() {

    }

    Node(group g, Node next) {
        this.data = g;
        this.next = next;
    }

}


public void addGrp(Scanner sc) {

    sc.nextLine(); // NOTE: Added to 'consume' the new line character left over by sc.nextInt()
    try {
        
            if(list==null)
            {
                System.out.println("enter the name of your project group");
                String groupname = scn.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter Group lead Name");
                String lead=sc.nextLine();
                group grp1=new group(groupname,lead);
                System.out.println("members are");
                
                for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
                {
                    grp1.members[i]=sc.nextLine();
                }
                
                Node n1=new Node(grp1,null);
                
                head=n1;
                list.add(n1);
            }
            else
            {
                Node start=head;
                while(start!=null)
                {
                    start=start.next;
                }
                System.out.println("enter the name of your project group");
                String groupname = scn.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter Group lead Name");
                String lead=sc.nextLine();
                group grp1=new group(groupname,lead);
                System.out.println("members are  ");
                
                for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
                {
                    grp1.members[i]=sc.nextLine();
                }
                Node n1=new Node(grp1, null);
                start.next=n1;
            }
    }catch (Exception e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
            
 
//Print all elements of the Array
public void display() {
    Node start=head;
    while(start.next!=null)
    {
        group g1=start.data;
        System.out.println("Group Name = "+ g1.grpname+"  Leader Name = "+ g1.leadname);
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(g1.members[i]);
        }
    
    }
}

public static void main(String arg[]) {
    LinkedListDemo ll = new LinkedListDemo();
    // Creating an empty LinkedListLinearLinkedList obj= new LinearLinkedList();

    int ch;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("\n1.addGrp\n2.display\n3.displayallgrps\n0.Exit");
        ch = sc.nextInt();
        switch (ch) {
            case 1:
                ll.addGrp(sc);
                break;
            case 2:
                ll.display();
                break;
            case 3:
                ll.allgrp();
                break;
            case 0:
                ll.exit();
                break;
        }

    } while (ch != 0);

    sc.close();

}

public void allgrp() {
    for (String elements : list)
        System.out.print(elements + " ");
    Node current=head;
    while(current!=null)
    {   for(int i=0;i<=6;i++)
        {
        
            System.out.print(current.data + " ");
            current=current.next;
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
        
    
}

public void exit()
{
    System.out.println("thanks for using the code!!!");
}

}
```

Comment: You have created a list for String object `LinkedList<String> list` and you try to put Node object in it. you can't, that seems normal , not for you ? And at the end you iterate over it using String, you have to decide what you wan't to store in it

Comment: i want to store an node object and want to show it at last in display what changes would you recommend

Comment: make the list stores Node instead of String ? Do you understand what we're talking about ?

Comment: I'd strongly advise you not to even *try* to run code that doesn't compile. Fix compilation errors before trying to run. (If your IDE gives you the option of running non-compiling code, disable it!)

Comment: @azro i did this LinkedList<group> list = new LinkedList<group>(); this what you want me to do

Comment: You said "i want to store node", you wrote `list.add(n1)`, why do you use group so ?

Comment: for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
             {
              grp1.members[i]=sc.nextLine();
             }
             
             Node n1=new Node(grp1,null);
             
             head=n1;
             list.add(n1); because in this n1 node i am storing object of class grp1 which has my members stored in that object @azro

Comment: So do `LinkedList<Node>` it you put Node in it